# Azure pipeline EACH issue

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, each, azure-pipelines-yaml

I found a lot of examples about using EACH loop in an Azure pipeline, but all of them I found are using a parameter as the array.
What about using an array that was created in the code?
I mean:

```
  - script: COMMAND=$(npx nx affected:apps --base=$(BASE_SHA) --head=$(HEAD_SHA) --plain) && echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=APPLICATIONS;]$COMMAND"

  - task: Bash@3
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
          echo 'APPLICATIONS + $(APPLICATIONS)'
          readarray -d ' ' -t ARRAYAPPS <<<'$(APPLICATIONS)'
          echo ${ARRAYAPPS[0]}
          echo ${ARRAYAPPS[1]}
  
  - ${{each APPLICATION in $APPLICATIONS }}:
  - task: ...
```

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72530649/174843

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"If you're blocked in a way, try to change this way"
I modified the approach, and I included the loop inside the bash script:

```
readarray -d ' ' -t ARRAYAPPS <<<$(APPLICATIONS)
if (( ${#APPLICATIONS[@]} > 0 )); then
  for (( i=0; i<${#APPLICATIONS[@]}; i++ ));
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Pipeline `${{each` does not support runtime pipeline variables. It only supports parameters, because the *each* is evaluated at compile time; and at that time, it is only parameters (and variables based on them) that are available.