# How to use a variable in each loop in Azure DevOps yaml pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a PowerShell script in my Azure DevOps pipeline:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Get_records
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
        <...>
        $records.Records
```

**$records.Records** is some variable which contains array of records. I need to use this data this way: for each record in this array I need to perfome several tasks within one job. Something like this:

```
stages:
- stage: stage_1
  jobs:
  - job: Job_1

    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: Get_records
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          <..getting this records..>
          $records.Records

    - ${{each records in variables.records.Records}}:

      - task: not_powershell
        displayName: name1
        inputs:
          AsyncOperation: true
          MaxAsyncWaitTime: '60'
    
      - task: not_powershell
        displayName: name2
        inputs:
          AsyncOperation: true
          MaxAsyncWaitTime: '60'
```

How can I do that? There are a couple questions about this:

1. How to use '$records.Records' variable in foreach loop? Must I save variable before using? If yes - how to save an array?
2. If it is imposible to do it this way, probably there are some ways around, for example use several stages, jobs... etc?

Comment: `$records.Records |ForEach-Object { <# access current record via $_ #>}`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I dont undesrtand, I am newbie in Azure and PowerShell. Can you give me full usage example please?

Comment: That's it. The code inside the curly brackets will run once for each item in the `$records.Records` array, with `$_` automatically assigned the value of the current item.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen that will only work *inside a powershell script* though; it's not going to work in a yaml pipeline

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen It's example for PowerShell script. right? In my case I need to perfome non-powershell scripts in my loop.

Comment: @EaredGen - TWO very different things:
1) a powershell stript in a .ps1 file that is called from the YAML
2) a sequence of powershell commands that are inline WITHIN the YAML.

In the latter you have to deal with the fact that YAML will transform what you put in to create a TEMPORARY PS1 so many things are already substituted before the script is run)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**No, you can't. It only works for [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops), not variables:**

> [You can use the each keyword to loop through parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#each-keyword)

This is because:

- before it runs, the yaml is parsed and [compiled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runs?view=azure-devops#process-the-pipeline) into a pipeline structure, with all the stages, jobs and tasks defined. This is the point when the loop condition is evaluated, and the loop is expanded into multiple stages/jobs/tasks.
- [dynamic runtime variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts) are not yet available at compile-time, so they cannot be used at this point to define the each loop.
- at runtime, when the dynamic variable is available, the pipeline structure is already fixed, so it is not possible to add extra tasks at this point.

**Workaround**

You *can't* loop over a dynamic array variable in the pipeline; but one place you *can* do so is within a task, for example within a [powershell script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops):

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Loop Over Records
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # first, get the records
      ForEach ($record in $records.Records) {
        # do something with $record
      }
```

That isn't as powerful as a pipeline loop, with all the different types of non-powershell tasks available, but it might be the only way to loop over this array.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that I can't pass this array to next PowerShell task? It would be great work with data in separate task. I tried this (in script where I get data):

Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=records;]$records.CrmRecords")

And in following task:
$records =  $env:records
ForEach ($record in $records) {
   $record
 }

But it doesn't work as I want and output 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Management.Automation.PSObject]'.

Comment: You can pass the array to another task, yes; but all pipeline variables are just strings, so you will have to convert the array to some kind of string format in order to do so. JSON, for example.

Comment: Thanks for this - it's super misleading on MSFTs side as the top of the Expressions page says "Expressions can be evaluated at compile time or at run time."

Comment: It doesn't work for a different reason. `each` can be used with variables, you can find an example on the same expressions page you link under [`split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#split). The reason it doesn't work is because `${{}}` is a "compile-time expression" (see the same expressions page near the top) it will only work for variables available at that "compile-time", so it cannot be used with a variable created by a task.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is quite old but I was looking for a solution to this problem and I found this **work-around** that works for me (@nOrd mentioned something in the comments).

```
variables:
- name: records
  value: record1,
    records2,
    record3

steps:
- ${{ each rec in split(variables.records,',') }}:
  - pwsh: |
      echo  ${{ rec  }}
displayName: Show ${{ rec }}
```

In your case you could try something like this:

```
variables:
- name: newrecords
  value: $[variables.records.Records] 
 
steps:
- ${{ each rec in split(variables.newrecords,',') }}:
  - pwsh: |
      echo  ${{ rec  }}
    displayName: Show ${{ rec}}
```

Note that the variable has *template expression* syntax, so the variable is evaluated at compile time (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#runtime-expression-syntax)