# Use Azure DevOps variable in parameters section in azure pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a DevOps variable group with a variable like that: `VARIABLE=['a', 'b', 'c']`.

Then in Azure pipeline, there is a parameter like that:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: parameter_test
  displayName: 'Test paramter'
  type: string
  default: a 
  values:
  - a
  - b
  - c
```

I want to use the variable instead of the hardcoded list, since it's present in multiple pipelines. Tried this, but docs say I can't use expressions in parameters section:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: parameter_test
  displayName: 'Test paramter'
  type: string
  default: a 
  values:
- ${{ each group in variables.VARIABLE }}:
  - ${{ group }}
```

Have you ever tried things like that or have any idea how to parametrize it?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hey you can use something like a variable group  refer the following docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: @MohitGanorkar I use it, the problem is I cannot use this variables in the 'parameters' section :((

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a variable in each loop in Azure DevOps yaml pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72528343/how-to-use-a-variable-in-each-loop-in-azure-devops-yaml-pipeline)

Answer (score 1):

According to this document [Variable groups for Azure Pipelines - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#use-a-variable-group), to reference a variable group, use macro syntax or a runtime expression, therefore the parameter cannot be defined with the value of variable from a variable group.

Instead of defining the parameter with the value of the variable in a variable group, you may consider using a core YAML to transfer the parameter/variable value into a [YAML Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops). Kindly refer to the below sample YAML pipeline.

```
# Core YAML
trigger:
- none
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
variables:
- name: Variable_core
  value: b
parameters:
- name: Parameter_core
  default: c
  values:
    - a
    - b
    - c
steps:
  - template: Parameters.yml
    parameters:
      parameter_test_Azure_Repos_1: ${{ variables.Variable_core }}
      parameter_test_Azure_Repos_2: ${{ parameters.Parameter_core }}
```

```
# Parameters.yml from Azure Repos
parameters:
- name: parameter_test_Azure_Repos_1
  displayName: 'Test Parameter 1 from Azure Repos'
  type: string
  default: a
- name: parameter_test_Azure_Repos_2
  displayName: 'Test Parameter 2 from Azure Repos'
  type: string
  default: a
steps:
- script: |
    echo ${{ parameters.parameter_test_Azure_Repos_1 }}
    echo ${{ parameters.parameter_test_Azure_Repos_2 }}
```

[image: echo b & c]

Answer (score -1):

All non yaml files is not recommended as this is not as code, very difficult to check & audit & versionning, so as to variable group, release pipeline etc.

Azure pipeline has indeed some limitations, we can reuse the variables but not the parameters.

If I was you, even multiple pipelines use the same parameter, I will still "hard code" this directly in the pipelines just like what you wrote:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: parameter_test
  displayName: 'Test paramter'
  type: string
  default: a 
  values:
  - a
  - b
  - c
```