# In AzureDevops , trying to run a yaml file to trigger a powershell script - how can i assign different environment values to script

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, yaml

In AzureDevops , trying to run a yaml file to trigger a powershell script - how can i assign different environment values to script so that it runs for all environment.

```
parameters:
  - name: environmentName
    type: string
    default: 'PROD'
  - name: azureSubscription
    type: string
    default: 'ABC-Prod'
    
  - job: ABC
    variables:
      - group: 'ABC-${{ parameters.environmentName }}'
        
    steps:
      - task: AzurePowerShell@5 
        inputs:
          #azureSubscription: 'ABC-nonprod-dev'
          scriptType: 'FilePath'
          azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
          scriptPath: 'src/databricks/ABC.ps1'
        displayName: 'ABC Databrick Job'
```

Now this job needs to be run in DEV, UAT and PROD and azureSubscription - 'ABC-nonprod-dev','ABC-nonprod-uat' and 'ABC-prod'

How we can run a loop in powershell so that ABC.ps1 script can run for all 3 environments

Answer (score 0):

To create foreach you can use expressions combined with 'each' keyword  providing list of environments as a object

```
parameters:
- name: environments
  type: object
  default:
  - dev
  - prod

steps:     
- ${{ each value in parameters.environments}}:
  - script: echo ${{ value }}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script#loop-through-parameters

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#each-keyword

Comment: You cannot use 'each' for variables, only for parameters https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72528343/how-to-use-a-variable-in-each-loop-in-azure-devops-yaml-pipeline