# Create dynamic steps based on a previous stage's runtime output variable

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I try to create job steps in runtime with the previous stage variable which was also created in the runtime. I follow the [Set an output variable for use in future jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#set-an-output-variable-for-use-in-the-same-job) example with some changes.

```
name: Playground
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  - group: main
  - name: System.Debug
    value: true

stages:
  - stage: A
    jobs:
    - job: A1
      steps:
      # Get commit change paths from REST API, then join them with comma and put it into the myStageVal variable
      - script: |
              result=$(curl --location 'https://dev.azure.com/$(org)/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/git/repositories/$(Build.Repository.Name)/commits/$(Build.SourceVersion)/changes?api-version=5.0' \
                --header 'Authorization: Basic $(PAT_base64)' \
                | jq '.changes[].item.path' \
                | tr '\n' ',')
              echo $result
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myStageVal;isOutput=true]$result"
        name: MyOutputVar

  - stage: B
    dependsOn: A
    jobs:
    - job: B1
      variables:
        myStageAVar: $[stageDependencies.A.A1.outputs['MyOutputVar.myStageVal']]
      
      steps:
        # echo works fine
        - bash: echo $(myStageAVar)

        # try to generate steps from myStageAVar is not working
        - ${{ each var in split(variables.myStageAVar, ',') }}:
          - script: |
              echo ${{ var }}
            displayName: Printing ${{ var }}
```

When the pipeline run, my stage B1 raise error on `displayName: Printing ${{ var }}` steps.

`/home/vsts/work/_temp/11476078-561a-41c8-8177-9d27a9bf3f81.sh: line 1: stageDependencies.A.A1.outputs['MyOutputVar.myStageVal']: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".A.A1.outputs['MyOutputVar.myStageVal']")`

It seems template expression (${{ }}) cannot handel variable `myStageVal` define at runtime.

How can I create steps in runtime base on variable define at runtime?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a variable in each loop in Azure DevOps yaml pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72528343/how-to-use-a-variable-in-each-loop-in-azure-devops-yaml-pipeline)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the `${{ }}` syntax during runtime. These expressions are expanded when the pipeline is "compiled" (in lack of a better word).

During runtime, you can only use `$[]` and `$()`. These, however, cannot be used on the right-side expressions, so they cannot be used in your for-each loop.

It is not possible to generate steps during runtime as you are attempting to do, as the whole pipeline is compiled before it is run.

I have solved a similar issue in the past by starting a new pipeline. In short, you can do this:

1. Pipeline 1 (matching stage A) runs. When it is finished, it uses the azcli to trigger a new pipeline. The output variables from (1) is used as input parameters when triggering pipeline 2.
2. Pipeline 2 (matching stage B) is triggered from Pipeline 1. As the variables from (1) is now passed as parameters to (2), you can use the `${{ }}` syntax and the tasks you want will be compiled before (2) starts.

This will reach the design you want. However, bare in mind that it will visually look like two pipelines in Azure DevOps and it migh be difficult for a user to fully understand how the pipelines trigger each other.

It is also a bit messy to trigger another pipeline through the azcli with parameters.